# Edited - How to fix "ERR_CONNECTION_RESET" .Net Core Web API on Linux

Tags: c#, linux, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm setting up a linux server to host a .net core application.
I have already configured the .net core sdk and the nginx.

Before trying to publish my application there I've tested with the samples that .net core provides.

Firstly I have created a simple mvc with "dotnet new mvc" and it worked fine. Then I created a webapi sample using "dotnet new webapi". It also worked fine. When I called the endpoint /api/values it returned the result but just for some seconds.

After like 15s it started to throw **"ERR_CONNECTION_RESET"** using Chrome. When I stop the application and run it again, the api works correctly, but then stops again after seconds.

The same happens for my webapi application with other endpoints.

I'm using **.Net Core 2.1.301-5** and **Linux Redhat**. I have already tried adding the code below, but it didn't work as well.

```cs
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);
```

Does anyone have an idea of what can I do to solve this?

---

Edit:

I have discovered that this only happens when I use WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args) on the Program.cs. When I use new WebHostBuilder() instead, the error does not happen, but I can't get the configuration from appsettings.json.

Comment: Try to enable [Log creation and redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-2.2#log-creation-and-redirection) to see whether there is any detail error.

Comment: @TaoZhou do you know how can I do it on Linux? There's no web.config